# Error CS0121 ambiguous call for ConfigureApplicationCookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects. I get that a method call when building the web application causes an ambiguity call when I execute the command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout"
```

When I build the application using `dotnet run` it works fine.

The process of scaffolding stops after this, so it means the built went through but stops when trying to generate the codes:

```
Finding the generator 'identity'...
Running the generator 'identity'...
Failed to compile the project in memory
```

Code that gives the ambiguity error:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Full error message:

```
error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureApplicationCookie(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions>)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureApplicationCookie(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions>)'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:05.05
```

I'm not sure how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks the two methods in  your error are the same method.`'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureApplicationCookie(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions>)'`For the same method,it should not get the error.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, the same so I decided to just not scaffold and write the code by my own...